# Avoid traversing included system libraries

Tags: llvm, clang

I'm working with **LLVM** + **Clang** now. I use the **ASTUnit** to build-up the tree and I use the **RecursiveASTVisitor** to traverse the tree.

```
    clang::ASTUnit* AST;
    clang::DiagnosticOptions diagOpts;
    llvm::IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::Diagnostic> diags = clang::CompilerInstance::createDiagnostics(diagOpts, 0, 0);

    const char** ptr = new const char*[1];
    ptr[0] = argv[1];

    clang::CompilerInvocation *ci = new clang::CompilerInvocation();
    clang::CompilerInvocation::CreateFromArgs(*ci, ptr, ptr+1, *diags);
    ci->setLangDefaults(clang::IK_CXX, clang::LangStandard::lang_cxx98);
    ci->getPreprocessorOutputOpts().ShowComments = 1;
    ci->getPreprocessorOutputOpts().ShowLineMarkers = 1;

    AST = clang::ASTUnit::LoadFromCompilerInvocation(ci, diags);

    ...
    ...

    MyRecursiveASTVisitor myvis(AST->getASTContext());
    myvis.TraverseDecl(AST->getASTContext().getTranslationUnitDecl());
```

I would like to avoid visiting the included system libaries. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found some kind of solution, but not the final one!

In the inherited ASTVisitor class:

```
class MyRecursiveASTVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<MyRecursiveASTVisitor>
```

You can override function **TraverseDecl**. In this function you can traverse the declarations. If you don't call this function recursive, when the declaration is not from the main file, you can avoid traverse the declarations from other files.

```
bool TraverseDecl ( clang::Decl *D )
{
    bool rval;

    if (!D) return true;

    if (sm.isFromMainFile(D->getLocation()) || std::string(D->getDeclKindName()) == "TranslationUnit")
    {
        bool rval = clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<MyRecursiveASTVisitor>::TraverseDecl(D);
    }
    else
        rval = true;

    return rval;
}
```

In this context the **sm** is the **clang::SourceManager** of class **MyRecursiveASTVisitor**. You van avoid traversing statements from other files, the same way, in overridden **TraverseStmt** function.

Now I only how to get to know whether the statement or declaration is from a system library, or a user defined library.